# MSBuild - assembly version resolution

Tags: .net, msbuild, tfsbuild

We have multiple build agents running a build for a project which includes a reference to Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap (Version=12.0.0.0). Oddly the build completes fine one build server but doesn't on the other.

The specifics of the issue are that the project explicitly references version 12 (although the specific version property is set to false) which is resolve correctly on one build agent, but on the failing build server it resolves the reference to an earlier version -. Version=11.0.0.0.

I can see from the build output that it can't resolve the reference from the hint path, and therefore probes for the dll. What I can figure out is what tells the compiler where to probe.

I've highlighted the diff that I think is significant in the build output below, but still haven't worked out why it resolves to Version 11.0.0. on one build server, and 12.0.0 on the other.

Any thoughts/help would be gratefully appreciated.

Build output below :

***OUTPUT FROM COMPILATION ON WORKING BUILD AGENT***

Primary reference "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91".
      Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll".
      Reference found at search path location "{AssemblyFolders}".
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "........\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll", but it didn't exist.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.exe", but it didn't exist.
          For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft.NETFramework,v4.0,AssemblyFoldersEx}".
          Considered AssemblyFoldersEx locations.
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll", which existed but had a processor architecture "X86" which does not match the targeted processor architecture "amd64".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll", which existed but had a processor architecture "X86" which does not match the targeted processor architecture "amd64".
          ***For SearchPath "{AssemblyFolders}".
          Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.winmd", but it didn't exist.
      This reference is not "CopyLocal" because its types will be embedded into the target assembly.
      ***The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0.30319".******

***OUTPUT FROM COMPILATION ON FAILING BUILD AGENT***

Primary reference "Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91".
      Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll".
      Reference found at search path location "{AssemblyFolders}".
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          considered "........\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\120\sdk\assemblies\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.dll", but it didn't exist.
          for searchpath "{targetframeworkdirectory}".
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework.netframework\v4.0\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework.netframework\v4.0\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.dll", but it didn't exist.
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\reference assemblies\microsoft\framework.netframework\v4.0\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.exe", but it didn't exist.
          for searchpath "{registry:software\microsoft.netframework,v4.0,assemblyfoldersex}".
          considered assemblyfoldersex locations.
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\120\sdk\assemblies\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.dll", which existed but had a processor architecture "x86" which does not match the targeted processor architecture "amd64".
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\110\sdk\assemblies\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.dll", which existed but had a processor architecture "x86" which does not match the targeted processor architecture "amd64".
          ***for searchpath "{assemblyfolders}".
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\windows installer xml v3.6\sdk\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.winmd", but it didn't exist.
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\windows installer xml v3.6\sdk\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.dll", but it didn't exist.
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\windows installer xml v3.6\sdk\microsoft.sqlserver.dtsruntimewrap.exe", but it didn't exist.
          considered "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sql server\110\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.winmd", but it didn't exist.
      This reference is not "CopyLocal" because its types will be embedded into the target assembly.***
      ***The ImageRuntimeVersion for this reference is "v4.0".***

Comment: Well, you could start by not giving it such a hard time to find the proper reference assembly.  Target AnyCPU instead of x64 and ensure that the HintPath points to a good directory on the build server.

Comment: Thanks Hans, The Release configuration is set to AnyCPU for the project in question, and the hint path was set by Visual Studio. The path to the file in the properties window is :\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\ but the hint path is relative not absolute, which in the case of the build agent it's in correct.

Comment: Interestingly the hint path is incorrect for the build agent that works. Neglecting the hint path for a moment, there's something else that's telling the compiler where to resolve references from -> {AssemblyFolders}. This seems to differ between agents somehow. I've checked the registry but the AssemblyFolders refer to a different path than the ones used, i.e. c:\program files  rather than c:\program files (x86)\.